# How to pass a connection string into an SSIS file?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS file created using the Import and Export wizard. Using that wizard seems to hard-code the connection string into the SSIS file; what I'd like to do is pass the connection string into the file so that I can configure the target database. Anybody know how to do this?

*edit* A little more info: Technically I've got 17 SSIS packages that I am executing from a PowerShell script using dtexec. I'd like the PowerShell script/dtexec to be able to pass the connection string into each SSIS package. I created these packages using the SQL Server Import/Export wizard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming the package is in C:\ssis, your connection manager is named MyConnectionManager, this will override the the value and point it to localhost.

```
dtexec /file C:\ssis\pkg1.dtsx /conn "MyConnectionManager";"\"Data Source=localhost\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;\""
```

Comment: Your answer put me on the right path, though my solution ended up needing to look like this: dtexec /file C:\ssis\pkg1.dtsx /conn "MyConnectionManager;Data Source=localhost\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Answer (score 1):

The sample provides the best simple solution to promote the SSIS across environment. Refer the below blog by Rafael Salas to understand more options.
[Understanding Integration Services Package Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use graphic shell of dtexecui to configure parameters of package. This UI has a tab "Command line", where you can find all parameters, converted to command string, which you can use as parameter to console dtexec.
You can get step-by-step example here http://sqlstudies.com/2013/07/31/using-dtexecui-to-generate-a-dtexec-command-line-statement-the-easy-way/