# SQL table content update from external data source

Tags: sql, sql-server, automation, data-migration

I am not sure how to ask this question so please direct me in the right direction if I am not using the appropriate terminology, etc. but I can explain what I am currently doing. I would like to know if there is an easier way to update content in the database than the method I'm currently using.
(I'm using SQL Server 2008 BTW.)

I have a bunch of CSV files that I use to give to my client as a means to update content which gets imported into the DB (because the content is LARGE). The import works by running a python script that I wrote that makes use of a Jinja2 template that generates the SQL file needed to insert the CSV content into the database (if it is a from-scratch scenario). This is working fine.
Now when it comes to data migration (I need to migrate the data that exists in the DB to a new version thereof) I have a lot of manual work (I hand code it in the template, there is no SQL command or auto-generated code that I can run to do this for me) to do.

So lets say I have a list of Hospitals in a CSV file and I already have a set of hospitals in the database (which is imported from the previous version of the CSV file). I create a copy of the Hospitals table (without the data) and call it HospitalsTemp. The new CSV hospitals are inserted into the HospitalsTemp table (at least that part is generated via the template).
The Hospitals table now gets detached from all its foreign-keys and constraints. Now I go through all the tables surrounding the Hospitals (again manually!) and replace the hospitalId which pointed to the old hospitalId with the new hospitalId (as I can do a lookup from the Hospitals to the HospitalsTemp based on the hospital code to ensure that referential integrity is retained).
Then I delete the Hospitals table and rename the HospitalsTemp to Hospitals and put back the foreign-keys and constraints on the new Hospitals table.

I hope I explained it well enough for everyone to understand. I'm really hoping for a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know which hospital becomes which, do the names stay the same? Is there an Id that stays the same?

Have you looked at SSIS, and the Slowly Changing Dimension component? You can use it to update existing rows and add new rows: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karang/archive/2010/09/29/slowly-changing-dimension-using-ssis.aspx

Also SSIS would be a good tool for the import, as it handles reading CSV files well.

You could replace the current logic with simple SSIS package that's just a flat-file data source and the output of the SCD wizard by the sounds of it?

Comment: I do have a hospital code that is used to pick up what has changed. Unfortunately not all CSV structures are straightforward, some of them are hierarchical and there are other CSV files that reference a second one with regards to those codes. I'll read the link you've posted, thanks.

Comment: SSIS might work but unfortunately I don't think we have licenses for this plus I have multiple environments to maintain my updates with, my dev box, the testing environment and the production environment. Production will definitely be out of reach for SSIS to even connect to. But I'll keep it in mind for future projects, this is something useful to know. Thanks.

Comment: SSIS comes with SQL Server, so if you have a licence for SQL Server you have a licence for SSIS :) The idea is you develop the SSIS package locally, then deploy it - In SQL 2008 you would run it as a SQL Server Agent task, and provide it with connection strings to use locally (So dev SQL agent passes a dev connection string, and so on): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688700/how-to-pass-a-connection-string-into-an-ssis-file