# SSIS in VS2010 - Trying to map an ODBC connection to a package variable

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to deploy my SSIS packages in a way that allows me to use variables to determine the connections to use, despite finding a fair amount of info on the subject nothing I do seems to work. I've setup a simple project with an SQL Task and an ODBC connection. I parameterized it and ended up with this:

[image]

But when I use the expression property of my SQL task to set the connection property to the connection variable I created I get an error:

[image]

Can I get a little help here on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell - you are addressing a wrong property.
At *Execute SQL Task* you have a ConnectionManager property which holds **name** of the connection manager, not the connection string itself. Thus, SSIS is reporting that it cannot locate a Conn Manager with name 'Dns=EA_Stage'. You need to specify expression on a Connection Manager itself, configuring ConnectionString property.
Alternative approach to your task - specifying Conn String from outside of package at runtime. It can be done with `DTEXEC` parameters directly [like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7695346/1010622). If used Project Deployment model, you can pass conn strings witn SSIS Catalog environments or address it with [DTEXEC /Par switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231187.aspx).